# Buck Boost Battery 3.6V (Lithium-thionyl Chloride) to 5V

Tags: low-power, battery-operated, buck-boost

I hope this question has not been asked and it's not as far as I have seen.

I am developing an IoT project which uses almost no current (< 100uA) when sleeping and up to 80mA when running. The problem is I need to power this with a battery which has to last quite a long time (1-2 years) and it doesn't have to be rechargeable. In particular I have found Lithium-thionyl Chloride to be pretty good at this and usually have a voltage of 3.6V at full charge.

My project runs on an ARM processor and the whole system works with an input from 3.6V to 6V and I'd like to input 5V. So I need to use a very efficient buck boost converter to go from 2/3.6V to 5V. This is how I am thinking to go about it.

If anyone knows a better way to power up this type of system I'd appreciate suggestions.

I'd prefer buying the complete circuit/product instead of building it but I can't find a good one on eBay. I can build one but I would really like to do that only in the worst case scenario.

Does anyone here know how to move about this?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a standard EVM like the one from [TPS61099EVM-768](http://www.ti.com/tool/tps61099evm-768) which features an IC with Vin from 0.7V to 5.5V and output voltage which can be set at 5V, while consuming 800nA.

Comment: Thats quite expensive. I don't think I can afford that for this project. But thanks.

Comment: It's only $0.58 /1k   You're looking at the eval board.

Comment: Oh okay thanks I didn't notice. I am not very familiar with the technical terms used for these converters so I am struggling to understand one thing. Does it it a minimum current load to work? Or not? Because as I wrote my project will require less than a mA in sleep mode. Thanks

Comment: Also one more thing. I need something which is through hole. Where could I find something like that? I'll try digikey

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you find the supply you need on ebay and its not that hard to build it by yourself.

I recommend to use the lowest possible supply voltage. Use 3v3 if no other devices really require the 5V.

During sleep you could switch off the input supply of the buck boost via an NMOS FET to save also the last micro amp leakage. Also the elko leakage is switched off then. And you can choose whatever DC-DC controller you like. But you need to think about how to implement the wakeup.

Use the lowest possible switching frequency for the DC-DC to reduce switching losses.

Try TI Webench online tool as this generates automatically complete designs with simulations. http://www.ti.com/ww/de/analog/webench/

Comment: Just for understanding. Why are you suggesting to use the lowest supply voltage? I suppose to minimize power consumption. Also what about using a battery that provides 3.6V and when discharges goes to 2.0V? That would mean the device wouldn't work because of lower voltage. That is why I thought to use a step-up regulator to 5V also because of some other components that I prefer to run at that voltage.

Comment: Most logic devices can operate with 5V or 3V3 or even lower. The boost has a higher efficiency when boosting from 3V Battery to 3V3 than to 5V. Some buck-boost converter support 100% on-time and you can use a 3,6V Battery